# Guest users are not permitted to perform this operation

Tags: lightning-web-components, graph, graphql

I am trying to apply the graphql to my publish lightning site.
I am using lightning-record-picker to find the contact from a published site.
But I got this error.
When rendering the site I got this and after I entered some characters in the search box I got the error in the capture below.
errorCode: "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS"
message: "Guest users are not permitted to perform this operation."
statusCode: 401

[image]

**I added the permission for the guest profile. Create a Sharing rule for the Account.
Add permission set but nothign work.**

Really appreciate for helping me!!!

This is my js.

```
@wire(graphql, {
    query: gql`
        query searchContacts($selectedContactRecordId: ID) {
            uiapi {
                query {
                    Contact(
                        where: { Id: { eq: $selectedContactRecordId }}
                        first: 1
                    ) {
                        edges {
                            node {
                                Id
                                Name {
                                    value
                                }
                                FirstName {
                                  value
                                }
                                LastName {
                                  value
                                }
                                Email {
                                  value
                                }
                                MobilePhone {
                                    value
                                    displayValue
                                }
                                MailingStreet {
                                  value
                                }
                                MailingState {
                                  value
                                }
                                MailingPostalCode {
                                  value
                                }
                                MailingCity {
                                  value
                                }
                                Title {
                                    value
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `,
    variables: '$variables'
  })
  wiredGraphQL({ data, errors }) {
    this.wireError = errors;
    if (errors || !data) {
      console.log('An error has occurred:');
      console.log(errors);
        return;
    }

    console.log('return data: ', JSON.stringify(data));
    if(data) {
      const graphqlResults = data.uiapi.query.Contact.edges.map((edge) => ({
        Id: edge.node.Id,
        Name: edge.node.Name.value,
        FirstName: edge.node.FirstName.value,
        LastName: edge.node.LastName.value,
        Email: edge.node.Email.value,
        MobilePhone: edge.node.MobilePhone.value,
        MailingStreet: edge.node.MailingStreet.value,
        MailingState: edge.node.MailingState.value,
        MailingPostalCode: edge.node.MailingPostalCode.value,
        MailingCity: edge.node.MailingCity.value,
        Title: edge.node.Title.value, 
      }));

      this.parentContact = graphqlResults?.[0];
      // //update parent field
      if(this.parentContact) {
        this.formData.parent.firstName = this.parentContact.FirstName;
        this.formData.parent.lastName = this.parentContact.LastName;
        this.formData.parent.email = this.parentContact.Email;
        this.formData.parent.mobile = this.parentContact.MobilePhone;
        this.formData.parent.street = this.parentContact.MailingStreet;
        this.formData.parent.state = this.parentContact.MailingState;
        this.formData.parent.zipcode = this.parentContact.MailingPostalCode;
        this.formData.parent.suburb = this.parentContact.MailingCity;
      }
    }
    
  }
  
  get variables() {
    return {
        selectedContactRecordId: this.selectedContactRecordId
    };
  }

  handleContactSelected(event) {
    this.selectedContactRecordId = event.detail.recordId;
    // console.log('contactId' , this.selectedContactRecordId);
  }
```

Comment: Where are you doing this? When you say sites, do you mean Experience Cloud? If so, not sure graphql is supported there yet:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/graphql/guide/graphql-wire-lwc-limitations.html

Comment: Yes, it is an Experience Cloud. I thought it wasn't supported yet. Anyway, thank you for your answer.